# Maximising $\mathbb{E}[X|X \geq c] - \mathbb{E}[X|X < c]$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ denote a continuous random variable. I want to find a distribution for $X$, preferably with support $\mathbb{R}_+$, such that
$$\mathbb{E}[X|X \geq c] - \mathbb{E}[X|X < c]$$
has a unique maximiser $c^* > 0$ in the **interior** of the support. It would be even better if it's easy to find $c^*$ in closed form.

To provide a motivation: imagine that have a class of students and that we will divide them into two groups, a top set (quality above $c$) and a bottom set (quality below $c$). We are then looking for the 'cut' $c$ that maximises the difference in average quality between the groups.

---

Some distributions I have tried:

(1) Standard uniform distribution (not ideal in any case due to the bounded support). But unfortunately, this generates
$$\mathbb{E}[X|X \geq c] - \mathbb{E}[X|X < c] = \frac{c + 1}{2} - \frac{c}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$
which is a constant (so has no unique maximiser).

(2) Exponential distribution. After calculating the conditional expectations, I find that

$$\mathbb{E}[X|X \geq c] - \mathbb{E}[X|X < c]  = \frac{e^{\lambda c} c}{e^{\lambda c}-1},$$
which seems to be strictly increasing in $c$ (so no maximiser).

Does anyone have better ideas? As I say, the support should be really be $\mathbb{R}_+$, but could conceivably be $[0, 1]$ (I do need all values in the support to be non-negative).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it might be helpful to have some sort of $\cup$-shaped density to see a local maximum, and that some $\cap$-shaped densities would have the opposite effect of introducing a local minimum.

$\mathbb{E}[X|X \geq c] - \mathbb{E}[X|X < c] \ge c -\mathbb{E}[X]$ so, if $c$ can be arbitrarily large, the difference will be too, and in particular will be unbounded above if you have support on all $\mathbb R_+$.

On $[0,1]$ there should be many examples, such as a $\text{Beta}(\frac12,\frac12)$ distribution with density $\frac1{\pi\sqrt{x(1-x)}}$ where the maximum difference of $\frac2\pi$ is at $c=\frac12$.  Adusting the parameters of the Beta distribution should make it possible to find other less symmetric examples.

Comment: thanks for the beta example, looks very helpful! Regarding your first point, I should add that a local minimum is in principle fine. All I want is a global maximum somewhere in the interior (and ideally, with support of the non-negative reals).

Comment: Thinking further, support on the whole of $\mathbb R_+$ cannot work in any example - I have edited my answer

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I understand that $c - \mathbb{E}[X]$ grows unboundedly. However, this is apparently an upper bound on the relevant expression, not a lower bound. So how does this show that the relevant expression grows unboundedly?

Comment: Also, may I check that the beta example is definitely right? When I calculated it just now, I found that it generates a difference $\mathbb{E}[X|X \geq c] - \mathbb{E}[X|X < c]$ that is strictly increasing on $[0, 1]$. But I may have made a mistake.

Comment: @afreelunch It is a lower bound since $\mathbb{E}[X|X \geq c]  \ge c$ and $\mathbb{E}[X|X < c] \le \mathbb{E}[X]$ but I made a typo on the inequality - now corrected.

Comment: For the $\text{Beta}(\frac12,\frac12)$ distribution I get $\mathbb{E}[X|X \geq c] - \mathbb{E}[X|X < c] = \left(1+\frac1\pi\right)-\left(1-\frac1\pi\right) \approx 0.637$ when $c=\frac12$ but clearly close to  $1-\frac12=0.5$ when $c\approx 1$ and close to  $\frac12-0=0.5$ when $c\approx 0$